# Angular routes event cycle is running twice when reloading a page with routes having queryParams

Tags: javascript, angular5

In my application, I have routes defined as follows:

**app-module.ts**

```
{ path: "myInbox", component: MyInboxComponent, data: { title: "My Inbox", activeRoute: "myInbox" },
children: [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "personal", pathMatch: 'full', data: { title: "My Inbox" } },
  { path: "personal", component: MassApprovalComponent, data: { title: "My Inbox", activeRoute: "myInbox/personal" } },
  { path: "pool", component: TaskClaimComponent, data: { title: "My Inbox", activeRoute: "myInbox/pool" } }
] }
```

Inside `MassApprovalComponent` (child component of My Inbox), I have different tabs. Clicking on these tabs, I am appending `queryParams` in html as follows:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item" (click)="switchTab('all')">
    <a class="nav-link small" [routerLink]="" [queryParams]="{tab: 'all'}" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedTab == 'all'}">All</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" (click)="switchTab('businessApproval')">
    <a class="nav-link small" [routerLink]="" [queryParams]="{tab: 'businessApproval'}" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedTab == 'businessApproval'}">Business Tasks</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="hasRole('FINANCE')" (click)="switchTab('financeApproval')">
    <a class="nav-link small" [routerLink]="" [queryParams]="{tab: 'financeApproval'}" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedTab == 'financeApproval'}">Finance Tasks</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="hasRole('BANKING_OPS')" (click)="switchTab('documentConfirmation')">
    <a class="nav-link small" [routerLink]="" [queryParams]="{tab: 'documentConfirmation'}" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedTab == 'documentConfirmation'}">Documents Confirmation</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="hasRole('BANKING_OPS')" (click)="switchTab('documentVerification')">
    <a class="nav-link small" [routerLink]="" [queryParams]="{tab: 'documentVerification'}" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedTab == 'documentVerification'}">Documents Verification</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Not lets suppose I click on `financeApproval` tab, now my routes in  address bar will be shown as `'<basePath>/myInbox/personal?tab=financeApproval'`

And when I copy this path and place it again in address bar and hit enter it's fine. But on reloading, I am being redirected to root path `<basePath>/`.

On setting `enablingTrace` to `true`, when I reload the page and see the console, I see the following two cycles.

***Navigation End of 1st cycle:***

```
NavigationEnd(id: 1, url: '/myInbox/personal?tab=documentConfirmation', urlAfterRedirects: '/myInbox/personal?tab=documentConfirmation')
```

***Navigation Start of 2nd cycle:***

```
NavigationStart(id: 2, url: '/myInbox/personal%3Ftab%3DdocumentConfirmation')
```

***Navigation End of 2nd cycle***

```
NavigationEnd(id: 2, url: '/myInbox/personal%3Ftab%3DfinanceApproval', urlAfterRedirects: '/')
```

And this is how I am handling reload in **app-component.ts** (**ngOnInit**) hook

```
this.router.events
      .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
      .map((route) => {
        while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
        return route;
      })
      .filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary')
      .mergeMap((route) => route.data)
      .subscribe((event) => {
        this.title = event['title'];
        /**
         * Code to handle route on reload
         */
        this.activeRoute = event['activeRoute'];

        //this.router.navigate([this.activeRoute]);
        if (event['isInvoices']) {
          this.currentNavigationList = "myInvoices";
        } else if (event['isMasters']) {
          this.currentNavigationList = "masters";
        } else if (event['isMOA']) {
          this.currentNavigationList = "MOA";
        } else if( event['isReports']) {
          this.currentNavigationList = "reports";
        } else {
          this.currentNavigationList = "";
        } 
        if(event['isSideNavItem']) {
          this.currentNavigationListItem = this.activeRoute;          
        } else {
          this.currentNavigationListItem = "";                    
        }
      });
```

Also, I am subscribing to routes in `MassApprovalComponent` as on tab selection routes are changing and then based on routes I am setting selectedTab which will configure the child component dynamically as follows:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.selectedTab = params['tab'];
      if(this.selectedTab == undefined){
        this.selectedTab = "all";
      }
      this.refreshApprovalTasksList();
    });
```